# Include variable in function

Tags: php

How can I get:

```
$img = new imageProcessing("333.jpg",200);
```

In a dynamic from considering cam_id=333

This is not working:

```
$img = new imageProcessing(" . $cam_id. '.jpg'",200);
```

Comment: `$img = new imageProcessing($cam_id.'.jpg',200); `

Comment: Your concatenating is just messed up! Simply: `$img = new imageProcessing($cam_id . ".jpg", 200);`

Comment: it needs the "" around the image name

Comment: @mark So you want the argument to be: `"333.jpg"` ?

Comment: In which case: $img = new imageProcessing('"' . $cam_id . '.jpg"', 200);

Comment: @mark No, it does not. Quotation marks are used to define literal strings. Variables, such as `$cam_id` can be used without them even if they represent string values.

Comment: I think he wants it to output "333.jpg", with the quotes, for whatever reason. @ Mark You can use single quotes ( ' ) and then put double quotes inside them, like $var = 'this is a "quote" ';

Comment: The other option, sorry, is: $img = new imageProcessing("\"$cam_id\".jpg", 200); - Using double quotes within double quotes can be done by 'escaping' them, by putting a backslash ( \ ) before them, like $var = "This is a \"quote\" "; And you can also use variables within double quotes without concatenating, like: $var = "Chris"; echo "My name is $var"; - will output My name is Chris.